# Orange lock screen

Tags: virtualbox, lock-screen, usability

When I lock my screen, I come back to an orange screen with a white clock and date in the middle. Getting out of this screen to get to the password screen is quite tedious. Clicking on the desktop doesn't work. Hitting escape sometimes works. Clicking on the animated arrows on the bottom of the screen sometimes works.

There has to be a way to get it so that it either stays on the password/cancel/unlock screen or so that any key gets it to the password/cancel/unlock screen.

This is maddening.

Ubuntu 17.10 in Virtualbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try swiping the screen upwards.

Comment: It's really hard. It means going keyboard/mouse/keyboard, and it works about 1/3 of the time and I wind up having to wait to see if it worked (which takes a few seconds) and, if not, trying it again. There has to be a better way. The previous version of Ubuntu didn't do this and I could just hit any key and it worked.